# Brick Rigs game breaking graphics glitch

Tags: brick-rigs

I opened up Brick Rigs today and there are green and pink bars flashing and moving across the screen like so:

[image: Pic of screen]

In the actual game, the colors are rapidly flashing in stripes.

Anyway, there has only been one update since I last played, a few days back. I have no explanation. Anyone get something that might help.

Comment: Does this happen in other games? Can you post a photo of your screen (now there's something I thought I'd never say)? Are your graphics drivers up to date?

Comment: @Studoku here's the best I can get. ^  It doesn't show up in screenshots, so I had to take this with my phone. Also, this happens in no other games, and I already tried reinstalling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed my resolution setting from "Fullscreen" to "Windowed". That simple.